# c++ Builder firemonkey and OSX static libraries

Tags: c++, macos, c++builder, firemonkey

I've created a static library with g++ on OSX with the following command:

```
g++ -static -c -o source1.o source1.cpp
g++ -static -c -o source2.o source2.cpp

ar rvs libmyosxsources.a source1.o source2.o
```

The library contains a source code like this:

```
int just_a_function(void);
int just_a_function(void)
{
  int p=0;
  int u= p +3;
  return u;
}
```

Now, I'd need to use the library function "just_a_function" from a c++ builder firemonkey project.
How can I do that?

Cheers

Dodo

Comment: Declare the function you want to call in the source, and link with the library you created?

Comment: It probably is impossible, add lib to your project and compile and see if it successfuly is compiled?